# Setting value of a djDateTextBox and djTimeTextBox?

Tags: xpages

How do I set the value of a djDateTextBox and djTimeTextBox component?

I tried 
getComponent("djDateTextBox1").setValue("10/12/2012");

but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lothar for putting me on the right track but this is how I solved it:

```
var sdt:NotesDateTime = doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("ContractorStartDateTime")[0];
var fdt:NotesDateTime = doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("ContractorFinishDateTime")[0];

getComponent("djDateTextBox1").setValue(sdt.toJavaDate());
getComponent("djTimeTextBox1").setValue(sdt.toJavaDate());

getComponent("djDateTextBox2").setValue(fdt.toJavaDate());
getComponent("djTimeTextBox2").setValue(fdt.toJavaDate());
```

Answer (score 1):

for me, this code here works just fine (is called by a button's server side onclick event, performing a full update):

```
getComponent("djDateTextBox1").setValue(@Today());
```

Otherwise you also could achieve a similar result using some client side script as in

```
dojo.byId("#{id:djDateTextBox1}").value = new Date();
```